# React-Bootstrap 2.2.0 Carousel Items stacking on each other

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a simple carousel with two items but they are stacking  right on top of one another rather than sliding between them.

```
<div className='test'>
    <Carousel controls={false} slide={true} bsPrefix='carousel' className='d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center'>
            <Carousel.Item className='d-flex' bsPrefix='c-item-1'>
                <div>
                <h1>Hospitals are in CRITICAL need of Blood!</h1>
                <p>There is currently a national blood shortage and it is affecting
                    our community! <br />Please, donate today.<br />
                </p>
                <Button variant='danger' >Find a drive</Button>
                </div>

                <div>
                <img
                className="d-flex"
                src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5340267/pexels-photo-5340267.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260"
                ></img>
                </div>
            </Carousel.Item>
            <Carousel.Item className='d-flex' bsPrefix='c-item-1'>
                <div>
                <h1>Hospitals are in CRITICAL need of Blood!</h1>
                <p>There is currently a national blood shortage and it is affecting
                    our community! <br />Please, donate today.<br />
                </p>
                <Button variant='danger' >Find a drive</Button>
                </div>

                <div>
                <img
                className="d-flex"
                src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5340267/pexels-photo-5340267.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260"
                ></img>
                </div>
            </Carousel.Item>
        </Carousel>
    </div>
```

Not sure what the issue is, this is how it I saw it formatted in the documentation. Any ideas?